# jQuery $.get or $.post doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone I have two PHP session variables which onclick I want to scrub the values of the two session values.

I have tried using $.get and $.post AJAX to get a external php page to run to clear down the session variables but it doesn't seem to work and I am not sure how I can debug it.

In the page that handles the click:

```
$('.ResetButton').click(function(){
    $('.tablesorter').trigger('sortReset');
    $.get("scripts/clear_sort.php", {ClaimSort:0}, function(data){});
    return false;
});
```

and clear_sort.php file contains:

```
<?php
    require ("scripts/session_handle.php");

    $_SESSION['ClaimSort'] = '';
    $_SESSION['ClaimSort2'] = '';
?>
```

ideas?

Comment: *"I am not sure how I can debug it"* http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your JS console.

Comment: Narrow down where the issue is, JS or PHP? Does the JS event fire?

Comment: Have you tried using `done()` and `fail()` callbacks to verify your PHP is being reached by the Ajax call?  You might want to echo a message in the PHP so you can verify the session variables are cleared.

Comment: paths don't make sense. . URL used in get says that file aready in `scripts` directory so your `require` doesn't make sense. One or the other is not right. Open network tab in browser dev tools...that request is either a 500 or 404 status

Answer (score 0):

there was no php errors as there was nothing wrong with the code. The JS was firing and was working OK.

Turns out I was an idiot when I was being lazy and copied the include and forgot to remove scripts/ so it was actually working all OK it just didn't initiate the session before trying to scrub the variables.

School boy! Thanks for the help.